# How to send an object of a model in Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, model, parcelable

I have a model and it `implements` the `Parcelable` interface, on my `MainActivity` I've like this

```
ArrayList<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
modelList.add(new Model( "name "+ i , "number "+ i));
```

And I have a `ListView` of this `modelList` items.

What I'm trying to do is that when the user clicks on an item of the list I use `Intent` and put its extra like `modelList.get(position)`

I just want to put a specific object of the model, and not the whole model like `intent.putParcelableArrayList("KEY", modelList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just need to do this

`Intent().putExtra("name", yourModel)`

`putExtra` has many overloads one of them is `putExtra(name : String, value : Parcelable)`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it in following way.

```
intent.putExtra("KEY",modelList.get(position));
```

and get it in following way in another activity

```
Model model=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("KEY");
```